# How should i check title using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, junit

Hey I can't resolve little problem. I have to check title of element on webpage using `cssSelector` or `xpath`. But I can't understand what command I should use to read elements title. Here is my code:

```
assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main-panel\"]/div[16]/a/dl/dd[1]")), "Создание, удаление и модификция пользователей, имеющих право доступа к Jenkins");
assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title=\"Управление пользователями\"] > dl > dd")), "Управление пользователями");
```

Xpath and cssSelector are correct. Here is HTML code if you need it

```
<a href="securityRealm/" title="Управление пользователями"><img src="/static/4be99593/images/48x48/user.png" alt="manage-option" class="icon"><dl><dt>Управление пользователями</dt><dd>Создание, удаление и модификция пользователей, имеющих право доступа к Jenkins</dd><dd></dd></dl></a>
```

Comment: use linkText for selecting an anchors title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will prove if the title of element is right:

```
assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Управление пользователями']")).getAttribute("title"), "Управление пользователями");
```

But I would say, if element with this cssSelector: `a[title='Управление пользователями']` was found, it is already means that it has title `Управление пользователями`. There is no need to prove it one more time with assert

Or if you want to check the text value of element, you can use this xPath:

```
//a/dl[contains(., 'Управление пользователями') and contains(., 'Создание, удаление и модификция пользователей, имеющих право доступа к Jenkins')]
```

and you could prove if such element exists like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/dl[contains(., 'Управление пользователями') and contains(., 'Создание, удаление и модификция пользователей, имеющих право доступа к Jenkins')]"));
```

if element will be not found, it will throw an exception.